# Extract array from javascript object

Tags: javascript, jquery, reactjs

I have below javascript object - (named Division)
I want to extract only SubDivs from the array

I tried : -

```js
const division = [{
    Name: "DivName1",
    Value: "DivValue1",
    SubDivision: {
      Name: "SubDiv1",
      Value: "SubDiv1"
    }
  },
  {
    Name: "DivName2",
    Value: "DivValue2",
    SubDivision: [{
        Name: "SubDiv2",
        Value: "SubDiv2"
      },
      {
        Name: "SubDiv3",
        Value: "SubDiv3"
      }
    ]
  }
]



var subDivs = division.map(x => x.SubDivision);
console.log(subDivs)
```

But this is **not giving** me array in format -

```
[{
Name:"SubDiv1",
Value:"SubDiv1"
},
{
Name:"SubDiv2",
Value:"SubDiv2"
},
{
Name:"SubDiv3",
Value:"SubDiv3"
}]
```

Comment: The object you shared at the start isn't a valid JavaScript object and throws a syntax error - can you clarify what your object looks like?

Comment: Next time create a [mcve] using the snippet editor, like I just did

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You can use flatMap for that

```js
const division = [{
    Name: "DivName1",
    Value: "DivValue1",
    SubDivision: [{
      Name: "SubDiv1",
      Value: "SubDiv1"
    }]
  },
  {
    Name: "DivName2",
    Value: "DivValue2",
    SubDivision: [{
        Name: "SubDiv2",
        Value: "SubDiv2"
      },
      {
        Name: "SubDiv3",
        Value: "SubDiv3"
      }
    ]
  }
]

const subdivision = division.flatMap(d => d.SubDivision)

console.log(subdivision)
```

Comment: This is working. Thanks.

Comment: @CSharper you're welcome and don't forget to accept the answer :)

Answer (score 1):

Given your example, all you need to do is call `flat` on the mapped array:

```
var subDivs= division.map(x=>x.SubDivision).flat();
```

Working example:

```js
const division = [{
    Name: "DivName1",
    Value: "DivValue1",
    SubDivision: [{
      Name: "SubDiv1",
      Value: "SubDiv1"
    }
  ]},
  {
    Name: "DivName2",
    Value: "DivValue2",
    SubDivision: [{
      Name: "SubDiv2",
      Value: "SubDiv2"
    },
    {
      Name: "SubDiv3",
      Value: "SubDiv3"
    }
  ]
  }
]

var subDivs= division.map(x=>x.SubDivision).flat();

console.log(subDivs)
```